# Revert Restore-SPFarm

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, central-administration, backup, restore

We have a SharePoint test server and SharePoint live server.

- They are on the same network
- The administrator for each is the same Active Directory account.

I know this is wrong but as a programmer in the development team, I have little influence over the infrastructure team's decisions.

What I have done is take backup in the Live server through the Central Administration (UI).

I copied the files to my test environment to test the backup.
I ran the following in powershell:

`Restore-SPFarm -Directory "copied backup directory in test server" -RestoreMethod overwrite`

I used overwrite as opposed to new, I think that's the **foolish** part.

I abruptly ended the restore on the Test Server. Now my live environment is not even loading. (I get 404).

Three questions:

1. I think what happened is that Restore-SPFarm worked on the live server even though it was invoked from the test server. Is this correct? Please let me know.
2. Any way to revert this? Maybe the restore command doesn't completely overwrite things on the content database? (hopeful thinking).
3. Should I be fired?

Thanks.

Comment: If your live environment has stopped working due to this, you must have executed the script on that server.

Comment: I was RDPing (remote desktop connection) on both servers at the same time, so I can't say that I am sure I wasn't running on the live. But I really think I was running on the test server.

Comment: About 1 I do not think so. It can not run on the live machine if it has been invoked on the test machine.
About 2, you have the backup, so why do not u restore it in live?

Comment: Pretty sure you ran it on the live environment, PowerShell can not operate on a different machine without some configuring and session-opening

Comment: The commands can run locally to cause effects on a remote computer. just like SharePoint online management shell. The sharepoint commands can connect to another server and invoke changes.

NKSP, yes that's what i want to do in case I am not able to revert. the only caveat is 2 days difference

Comment: I'll try it again on an isolated environment when  I have one and let you know if I can verify or not